# How to horizontally shift a histogram in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 1D array of numbers from which I need to plot a histogram in Python3. The bin boundaries are also available with me:

```
bins = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.hist(data, bins=bins, histtype='step')
```

Now, if I want to shift the histogram horizontally by 1 unit on the x-axis, how can I achieve that? I don't want the shape or the bin boundaries to change, I just want the whole histogram to move on the x-axis. If the histogram can be represented as f(x), I am looking for f(x-x0).

Comment: Can you add `data` ?

Comment: plt.hist(data + 1, bins=range(2, 6), histtype='step')

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, suppose you have

```
bins = np.arange(1, 6)
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,3,3])
plt.hist(data, bins=bins, histtype='step')
```

[image]

You can shift it by summing `x0` to your `data` *and* by modifying `bins` to allow for these changes. So, to shift it, say, by one unit

```
x0 = 1
plt.hist(data+x0, bins=np.arange(1, 6 + x0), histtype='step')
```

[image]

To shift by two,

```
x0 = 2
```

[image]

Comment: Ah no worries, I got it! The basic idea is to shift the data AND the bin boundaries by the same amount to imitate f(x) --> f(x-x0). Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @PiyushSharda exactly ! Glad I could help ;) I just kept the bins with the same starting point (`1` in your case) to show the shift clearly, but you can just add to every element to get the same graph in 1 with different x labels

Answer (score 0):

You could add or subtract `x0` to `data` before doing the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the matplotlib official doc :

xlocs, xlabs = plt.xticks()
put in xlocs your range, and in xlabs what you want to display.

then:

plt.xticks(xlocs, xlabs)